# How to make a Twitter bot run remotely and automatically

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy

I just built a Twitter bot with elevated access twith tweepy in Python. This bot retweets tweets containing a specific hashtag. It works just fine, but I have to click 'run' for it to find and retweet said tweets.

How can I make this run bot automatically? Note that I don't have much coding experience, I'm starting with the basics and I built this bot with the help of a few online tutorials.

Here's the code:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q='#myhashtag OR #myhashtag2').items(15):
    try:
        print('\nHi! I found this tweet by @' + tweet.user.screen_name + '. ')

        tweet.retweet()
        print('Retweeted.')

        # Where sleep(10), sleep is measured in seconds.
        # Change 10 to amount of seconds you want to have in-between retweets.
        # Read Twitter's rules on automation. Don't spam!
        sleep(5)

    # Some basic error handling. Will print out why retweet failed, into your terminal.
    except tweepy.errors.TweepError as error:
        print('\nError. Couldn't retweet. Reason: ')
        print(error.reason)

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean automatically as in online 24/7?

Comment: Yes! Exactly, I have no idea how though

Comment: You'd need to host it somewhere, maybe a home server or a cloud based one.

There's tons of options out there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).